# MySql query selecting top highest student scores including a must subject score

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am trying to archive here, is to select only the subjects a student is performing the best at, including a mandatory subject (`mustSubjectId`) and output the results depending on the grade range total.
The higher the `grade` the lower the point `add sum(marks)` as points.

Example input parameters:

```
$subjectlimit = '3'; // total subjects a student should pass including mandatory subject to qualify 
$idexam = '1'; // targeted examination id 
$mustSubjectId = '201'; // mandatory subjectid
$studentId = '1'; // a student to get
```

Table examinations

```
idcandidate | subject_id   | score
------------------------------------
1           |    200       | 30 
1           |    201       | 60 (note: a must subject)
1           |    202       | 80 
1           |    204       | 90 
1           |    203       | 50 
1           |    205       | 54 
1           |    209       | 37 
8           |    200       | 68 
2           |    200       | 20 
1           |    206       | 50
```

Table examrules

```
idexam          | marks       | grade
---------------------------------------
1               |    30       | 9 
1               |    45       | 8 
1               |    65       | 7 
1               |    70       | 6
1               |    80       | 5 
1               |    85       | 4 
1               |    90       | 3 
1               |    95       | 2 
1               |    100      | 1
```

Output with limit 3

```
Idcandidate| idexam   | subject_id| grade
1          |     1    | 204       |    3
1          |     1    | 202       |    5
1          |     1    | 201       |    8
```

Final Output

```
Idcandidate| idexam  | points
1          |     1   |    16
```

I hope that you can help as I am not good with complex MySql queries

**EDIT**

> I was mistaken by JNevill in the comments, the table examinations does
>   not have idexam and no relationship with examrules. The selection
>   should be something like
>
> Select top scores including mandatory subject score from examinations
>   where idcandidate = ‘1’ limit 3 then check the selected scores grade
>   in examrules where idexam = ‘1’ , the grades which will be found
>   should be calculated as points  sum (grade) as points

**AIM OF THE QUERY**

> There is a sheet showing the grades of all subjects of a class against
>   students, then on a certain row the sheet suppose to show the points
>   the student gets on 3 subjects including mandatory subject.  For a
>   student to pass examination he/she should pass three subjects
>   including mandatory subject.

**Note** 
the sql am running is reporting not to recognize select top and I also try on fiddle, fiddle didn’t recognize it too. `select top 3 score from examinations where idcandidate = ‘1’`

Comment: What is a "Must Subject"? I mean... how do you identify a "Must Subject" with this data, besides a note in a code block on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: $mustSubjectId has been fetched from database, there is  also a from which records such data into database, should i include that table?

Comment: I see now. We are in PHP or some such language and we are querying the database using the parameters above the list of tables. That is cool. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far? Then we can advise on where your problems might be.

Comment: there is also a table called passrate where there is subjectid which is a must subject and it can been joined using idexam

Comment: Bernd Linde sorry so far no query i have as am not even able to figure out how to just select the highest subjects. but appreciate much your hand

Comment: The difficult thing here is there no relationship between the two tables examinations and examrules. There is a way to write this query regardless, but it makes some assumptions about the relationship, namely that an idexam could be applied against many subject_ids. This seems like pretty a sloppy schema though since the relationship isn't explicit.

Comment: sorry i have to update my question examinations has also idexam

Comment: In your example `Output with limit 3` where does the `grade` of `8` come from for `subject_id` of `201`? Is it finding the next lowest `marks` in the `examrules` table and grabbing the `grade`?

Comment: JNeveil i would like to select highest scores of students including mandatory subject. that mandatory should be included either its fall or not

Comment: I understand that, but what I don't understand is how you get a score of `8` for `subject_id` `201`. Where does "8" come from? How do you determine it's 8.

Comment: its range of score of 201 subjectid

Comment: What's the grade for 44 score?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like (replace values with parameters as appropriate):

This gives you the top 2 highest scores that are NOT your 'must subject':

```
select TOP 2 en.idcandidate, en.idexam, en.subject_id, en.grade
FROM examinations en
INNER JOIN examrules er ON en.idexam = er.idexam
where en.subject <> $mustSubjectId
order by en.score desc
```

This gives you your 'must subject':

```
select en.idcandidate, en.idexam, en.subject_id, en.grade
FROM examinations en
INNER JOIN examrules er ON en.idexam = er.idexam
where en.subject = $mustSubjectId
```

This gives you your 'Output with limit 3' (just append one to the other):

```
select TOP 2 en.idcandidate, en.idexam, en.subject_id, en.grade
FROM examinations en
INNER JOIN examrules er ON en.idexam = er.idexam
where en.subject <> $mustSubjectId
order by en.score desc
UNION ALL
select en.idcandidate, en.idexam, en.subject_id, en.grade
FROM examinations en
INNER JOIN examrules er ON en.idexam = er.idexam
where en.subject = $mustSubjectId
```

And finally you add up the grades:

```
select idcandidate, idexam, sum(en.grade) as points FROM
(
    select TOP 2 en.idcandidate, en.idexam, en.subject_id, en.grade
    FROM examinations en
    INNER JOIN examrules er ON en.idexam = er.idexam
    where en.subject <> $mustSubjectId
    order by en.score desc
    UNION ALL
    select en.idcandidate, en.idexam, en.subject_id, en.grade
    FROM examinations en
    INNER JOIN examrules er ON en.idexam = er.idexam
    where en.subject = $mustSubjectId
) a group by a.idcandidate, a.idexam
```

I haven't had a chance to test this, but hope that helps!

Comment: There is some evidence to suggest that this question pertains to MySQL